# Convert Iterative Loop to Recursive Method

Tags: java, recursion, iteration

I got the exercise to write a function twice, once recursive, once iterative, which will produce the  following output:

```
private static void printSequence(int n)

printSequence(3);

1
12
123
12
1
```

My iterative solution is the following:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 2 * n; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= (i > n ? 2 * n - i : i); j++) {
        System.out.print(j);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

The iterative way is really simple, but I have no idea how to approach this as a recursive call.

Any tips on how to solve this problem?

EDIT: the method signature is fixed due to unit tests

Comment: You can create two recursive methods, one for printing numbers in one line, second to recursively print first and last rows (depending on input).

Comment: Hint: You want to print the first line, call a subroutine to fill in the middle, then print the last line. The subroutine then becomes exactly the same as the main method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code should look  like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    recusiveFunction(1,10); // First parameter is the iteration number and 2 is total times.
}

private static void recusiveFunction(int iteration ,int total) {
    String str="";
    for(int i=1;i<=iteration;i++){ // this loops creates what it needs to print 1 or 12 or 123
        str+=i;
    }
    if(iteration<total/2){
        System.out.println(str);
        recusiveFunction(++iteration,total);
    }
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Output:

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
1234
123
12
1
```

How this works is the we store the string in a variable that we want to print but we keep calling the function and increment the string is the iteration are less than half. then once it reaches half it start returning the stack trace so it gives us the return output in decreasing order.

---

## Edit :

As said by [pshemo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1393766/pshemo) modified the code a little bit to have absolutely no loops:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    recusiveFunction(1,10,"");
}

private static void recusiveFunction(int iteration ,int total, String str) {
    str+=iteration;
    if(iteration<total/2){
        System.out.println(str);
        recusiveFunction(++iteration,total,str);
    }
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Output:

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
1234
123
12
1
```

---

Alternative way:

```
public class Main {
    private  static int iteration=1;
    private  static String str ="";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printSequence(10);
    }

    private static void printSequence(int total) {
        if(iteration<=total){
            str+=iteration;
            System.out.println(str);
            iteration++;
            printSequence(total);
        }
        if(2*total - iteration >0) {
            str = str.substring(0, 2 * total - iteration);
            iteration++;
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
123456
1234567
12345678
123456789
12345678910
123456789
12345678
1234567
123456
12345
1234
123
12
1
```

Comment: You are using loops. I would say that purpose of this exercise is to learn to rewrite loops as recursive methods.

Comment: @Pshemo the loop is only for constructing the string the is to be displayed.

Comment: So it should be fairly easy to rewrite it as recursive method :)

Comment: The method signature is fixed, it gets tested with some kind of unit test framework so i can't change it up...
    private static void printSequence(int n)

Comment: @chamm Then just inside `printSequence(int n)` invoke `recusiveFunction(1, n, "")`

Comment: @chamm check the alternative way !

Comment: ok that will work i guess :D seems like my thought process just went nuts

Comment: Your one-argument-solution needs little improvements: (1) it doesn't print correct pattern, (2) if I understand method signature correctly `n` should be max value, not iteration counter.

Comment: @Pshemo made changes in the alternative way ! Please check if it is looks good !

Comment: It looks better but it generates few extra empty lines at the end. Also since `iteration` is not set to `0` after each method you can't reuse this method so `printSequence(3); printSequence(3);` will not work.

Comment: @Pshemo I feel the way to us this function is left to the uses ... so if the want to use it `printSequence(3); printSequence(3);` then the will have to reset str and iteration. As of the empty line I made a fix !

Comment: Simply use variation of my answer. Your code can look like http://ideone.com/OZlJmA

Comment: Here is little improved version of my previous example http://ideone.com/UDi5xo. It avoids recreating StingBuilder each time we use concatenation.

Comment: Anyway I would rather not to include it in your answer to avoid posting ready solutions. It is better if it will be hidden as comment to let others actually spend some time by themselves to improve or even rewrite your answer (I think it would be good exercise).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Your main recursive method can look like

```
void recursiveMethod(int iter, int max){
    if iteration<max
        print 1..iter
        recursiveMethod(iter+1, max)
        print 1..iter
    else
        print 1..iter
}
```

You can write additional recursive method which will handle printing numbers in range `1..n`

```
        print 1..iter
        recursiveMethod(iter+1, max)
        print 1..iter
```

should handle printing

```
1
..
1
```

but will also invoke `recursiveMethod(iter+1, max)` which will fill `..` part with

```
12
..
12
```

and so on, until case where `iteration==max` where we need to print only

```
123..max
```

Comment: this would be the way I would have solved it, but i can't add a parameter to the method signature due to unit tests which check my code

Comment: @chamm Like I said in my [previous comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26873488/convert-iterative-loop-to-recursive-method/26873864#comment42305632_26873695), you can simply invoke this recursive method inside method with fixed signature. Just set `iter` to `1` at start and let `max` be `n`.

Comment: In other words use `private static void printSequence(int n){ recursiveMethod(1,n); }`